# Verbatim inside tabular, inside a macro

Tags: macros, tabularx, minipage, verbatim

I would like to achieve a macro which makes a 2x2 table to show example inputs and outputs of a program (test cases). Something like this:

```
---------------------------
|input    | example input |
|--------------------------
|output   | example output|
---------------------------
```

"input" and "output" are always the same and just plain text, no problem with that. However, the example input and the example output may have multiple lines and spaces, and I would like to have the font \texttt gives. Naturally my mind went to verbatim environment, and I managed to make it work like this (inspired from other StackExchange posts):

```
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
\hline
    Input &
    \begin{minipage}{3in}
        \begin{verbatim}
5
1 2 3 4 5
3
        \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
    \\
    \hline
    Output &
    \begin{minipage}{3in}
        \begin{verbatim}
PRESENT
        \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

However, I am unable to put this into a \newcommand, to avoid code repetition. This code:

```
\newcommand\example[2]{
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
\hline
    sample &
    \begin{minipage}{3in}
        \begin{verbatim}
            {#1}
        \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
    \\
    \hline
    sample &
    \begin{minipage}{3in}
        \begin{verbatim}
            {#2}
        \end{verbatim}
    \end{minipage}
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

with a call to the macro (`\example{1}{2}`) gives a bunch of errors (*Runaway argument?*, *Missing \endgroup inserted.*, *Missing } inserted.*, *Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.*).

Aside of the fact that it feels like a trivial thing to do and I cannot make it work, it also feels like too many workarounds are going on, and the result looks unappealing. I am open to completely different approaches as long as it uses a humble amount of libraries, since I would like to get used to the basic functionalities of laTeX before exploring exotic packages.

Thank you!

Comment: you can not use `verbatim` in the argument of a command (including `\newcommand`)

Comment: Just a note: If input and output are always the same and should be formatted always the same, does it really make sense to print exactly the same twice?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the way i see it, in my solution the arguments of the command are simple text (1, 2), the verbatim is inside the `\newcommand`. Does this still mean that it cannot be used? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @cabohah by saying that they are the same I refer to the fact that they don't need to be arguments, they are hard-coded, just to avoid confusion about why I have only 2 arguments.

Comment: "verbatim is inside the `\newcommand`" that is what I meant, you can not use `verbatim` inside any command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, that's a bummer... thanks though!

Comment: your definition has a "normal" `\end{verbatim}` (where `\end` is a control token) but `verbatim` has turned off normal processing, so stops when (if:-) it sees the verbatim string `\ e n d { v e r b a t i m }` (not spaces, but `\end` is 4 character tokens)

Comment: *"I would like to get used to the basic functionalities of LaTeX before exploring exotic packages."* What about `\texttt{your code}`?  A minimal example with a true code sample could help to obtain better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't try s.th. like

```
\Example{...\end{verbatim}...}{...}
```

or

```
\Example{...}{...\end{verbatim}...}
```

, nesting verbatim (+v-type)-arguments inside `\scantokens`, as done in the example below, might do the trick.

Another important restriction with the example below is that `\Example` cannot be used successfully when being delivered as replacement-text of other macros or when coming from the arguments of other macros.
A more general statement, also covering these two cases is:
`\Example` cannot be used successfully in situations where the tokens forming its arguments did not come into being due to reading/tokenizing .tex-input during carrying out `\Example` and hereby having temporary category-code-settings introduced by `\Example` in effect, but are passed on to `\Example` in the course of expansion of other things/macros.

E.g.,

```
\newcommand\macro[1]{#1}...\macro{...\Example{arg 1}{arg 2}...}
```

won't work out.

```
\newcommand\macro{...\Example{arg 1}{arg 2}...}...\macro
```

won't work out either.

Here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begingroup
\NewDocumentCommand\Example{+v+v}{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\Example{+v+v}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}%
    \hline
    Input&%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}%
    \begingroup
    \newlinechar=\endlinechar
    \scantokens{#1##1#2}%
    \vskip\dp\strutbox
    \hrule height 0cm width 0cm %
    \end{minipage}%
    \\%
    \hline
    Output&%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3in}%
    \begingroup
    \newlinechar=\endlinechar
    \scantokens{#1##2#2}%
    \vskip\dp\strutbox
    \hrule height 0cm width 0cm %
    \end{minipage}%
    \\%
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}%
\newlinechar=\endlinechar
\Example{\endgroup
\expandafter\preto\expandafter{\csname @verbatim\endcsname}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt }%
\begin{verbatim}
}{
\end{verbatim}
%}%

% \expandafter\show\csname Example code\endcsname

\begin{document}

\noindent
\Example{5
1 2 3 4 5
3}{PRESENT}

\bigskip\noindent\hrule\bigskip

\noindent
\Example{e
a b c d e
c}{PRESENT, TOO}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If in the .tex-source-code/the .tex-input-file code denoting arguments of `\Example` is broken across lines, then indentation of these lines does matter.
Treatment of the horizontal-tab-character is as weird as usual with LaTeX's verbatim-mode.